# how can combine multi table with same columns in one common view model

Tags: entity-framework, linq, viewmodel

I have 14 tables with some same columns name and types.I want to Export them to excel.
How can I combine and Merge these common columns in one view Model in Entity Framework or Linq with One query ?
now I query 14 tables separately and convert to list and add them to common list.

```
var listAll = new List<requestViewExcel>();        
    listAll.AddRange(r1);
    listAll.AddRange(r2);
    listAll.AddRange(r3);
    listAll.AddRange(r4);
    listAll.AddRange(r5);
    listAll.AddRange(r6);
    listAll.AddRange(r7);
    listAll.AddRange(r8);
    listAll.AddRange(r9);
    listAll.AddRange(r10);
    listAll.AddRange(r11);
    listAll.AddRange(r12);
    listAll.AddRange(r13);
    listAll.AddRange(r14);
```

I don't like this Solution. is it another better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use **[Concat()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.8)**

```
var listAll = r1.Concat(r2).Concat(r3).Concat(...);
```

You can also use Union() but it will only return the unique items in the collections

Comment: thanks. Concat() translate my IQueryable to one query in sql that was with UnionAll.